# How to enqueue script or style in a theme's template file?

Tags: themes, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I am making a template for the page which will contain a slider.
Can anyone share some advice with me of how to go about it?

Comment: Please [search the site for related questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=enqueue%20script) before posting new questions.

Comment: @ChipBennett The information is still a bit vague.